Debian wont recognize Wi-Fi adapter
Bought this WiFi/Bluetooth PCI adaptor, on windows it bluetooth works only after installing the official driver at the developer official website and the wifi worked natively. But on Debian it was the opposite, the Bluetooth is working natively but the WiFi wont work, ant there is no Linux official driver on the developer website.
Running the lspci command it is shown as 04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev c3). 

My iwlwifi is already updated, my kernel is 6.1.0-20-amd64.

@AdminBee Correct, my mistake. Now, an Intel 7260 is fully supported. That said it may be missing the firmware or, more likely, because you have a dual-boot with Windows and forgot to disable Windows' Fast  Startup feature some devices can be 'hijacked between reboots.
